# Safely copy and convert fields to new fields without a WHERE in MySql

Tags: mysql

I need to encrypt some fields. I know I can't encrypt the current data into itself, so I will make new fields. Let's say "name" and "name_enc", "email" and "email_enc".
My test shows it does work on every row in a table if I leave out the WHERE qualification - but is this a **safe and reliable** technique?

```
UPDATE users SET name_enc= AES_ENCRYPT(name,'mykey'),  email_enc= AES_ENCRYPT(email,'mykey');
```

My concern is that if I was to do:

`UPDATE users SET name='fred'`

then every row would be set to 'fred'

Is MySql working out by itself that the rows I want updated are implicitly per row?

I'll only be doing it once but I need to be sure it's ok.
(Obviously the point is it saves doing loops and individual row UPDATES via PHP)

Comment: If you are updating all record, no need of `WHERE` clause. Otherwise `WHERE` clause is must. Better you try with single record with a `WHERE` clause & if its fine, continue without `WHERE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take this a bit at a time.

> I know I can't encrypt the current data into itself,

Actually you can, if you prepare the columns appropriately.

> so I will make new fields. Let's say "name" and "name_enc", "email"
>   and "email_enc".

This is hardly going to take you forward since you then store both he plain and ciphertext versions in the table. To achieve your ultimate aim, i.e. encrypted data, you still have to drop the original columns and rename the new ones you created (plus all the associated changes in your application).

> My test shows it does work on every row in a table if I leave out the
>   WHERE qualification - but is this a safe and reliable technique?

Yes, it's safe if the new columns are long enough to store the newly encrypted values. The target columns should be type VARBINARY and the column length needs to be calculated with

```
16 * (FLOOR(current_field_length / 16) + 1).
```

> UPDATE users SET name_enc= AES_ENCRYPT(name,'mykey'),  email_enc=
>   AES_ENCRYPT(email,'mykey');

This will work fine.

> My concern is that if I was to do:
>
> UPDATE users SET name='fred'
>
> then every row would be set to 'fred'

You are correct. It would do that because, unlike in your other example, you are not using the column name on the right-hand side of the assignment. Another example would be something like

```
UPDATE users SET age = 1;
```

Which would make everybody 1 year old. Compare with

```
UPDATE users SET age = age + 1;
```

Which would make everybody a year older.

> Is MySql working out by itself that the rows I want updated are
>   implicitly per row?

Yes.

Comment: Yup I know all that on encryption columns - I just wanted to confirm about MySql matching the rows - thanks